# Angular NgModel reevaluate getter @Input

Tags: angular, angular-forms

We are working on an angular project where we have a component that generates a list loaded via a getter and the list generates inputs that uses the ngModel directive. Each time we change the value in the inputs, the list of items gets reevaluated for some reason and rerenders our components which we do not want.

Here's an example that shows this behavior.

```
import {NgModule,ChangeDetectionStrategy,Component,OnChanges,SimpleChanges,Input} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <test-component [items]="getterList"></test-component>
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App implements OnChanges{
  staticList = ["a","b","c"];

  get getterList():string[]{
    console.log('getterList');
    return this.staticList.map(a=>a);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
    console.log(changes);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item}}
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="testValue" placeholder="ngModel" />
        <input type="text" [value]="testValue" placeholder="no ngModel" />
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() items:string[] = [];
  testValue:string="";
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App,TestComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

(here's the plunker)
https://plnkr.co/edit/MigjRs3MULcNS55oKVpp?p=preview

In this example we have a list generated via a getter. Each element of the list generates 2 inputs; one **with ngModel**, the other **without ngModel** and we can see that the second input doesn't trigger the getter.

Why does the ngModel directive retriggers the getter ?

Comment: What would be the usecase for a getter here, do you need it for something?

Comment: Yeah we map from an entity to another, we know we could do that once in the ngOnInit but we are trying to understand why the ngModel triggers the getter for no reason

Answer (score 0):

Well, the plunker was helpful. `[(ngModel)]` syntax is for 2-way binding. In your template, you use `[(ngModel)]="testValue"` which is the same for each iteration of the loop (the iterated element is `item` (of items, as per `*ngFor`). So basically all "first-inputs" in the loop's each iteration are all tied to one model property `testValue`. Because of 2-way binding it automatically updates the rest of the "first-input" fields. The second one is `[value]="testValue"` which uses only `[]` which is a one-way binding. hence it won't update the remaining fields.

If you remove `()` from `[(ngModel)]` so that it becomes just one-way binded like this, `[ngModel]`, you can see the difference. It will behave much like the second input field. So in essence it has nothing to do with your getters, all the magic is happening with the 2-way `[(ngModel)]` binding. Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is not the field and how it's applied on other fields. The problem is that the getter for the list is rettriggered when ngModel changes.

Comment: Like I said, it is due to the 2-way binding syntax. If you were to simply use, `[ngModel]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`, is it getting triggered?

Comment: We want the double binding, we just don't want the list to be regenerated for no reason via the parent's (AppComponent) getter when we change the field.